# How to make list out of objects in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I can add a single object to a list with this code and query:

```
makelist(A, B, C, X) :- append([1, 2, 3],A, X).

?- makelist(a, b, c, X).
X = [1, 2, 3|a].
```

However rather than the usual separator comma (,) there's a vertical line separator (|) and I cannot add another object to the same list:

```
makelist(A, B, C, X) :- append([1, 2, 3],A, X), append(X,B, X).

?- makelist(a, b, c, X).
false.
```

Comment: The only way for `append(X, B, X)` to succeed is if `B = []`. But in your case, `B = b`. Can you describe, in words, what relationship between `A`, `B`, `C` and `X` that `makelist` is supposed to define? And an example would help.

Comment: I thought `append(X, B, X)` would change list X in so that it would include B, rather than making a new list. The purpose of `makelist` was that an unknown number of objects could be returned with a query using one variable only. Since I posted the question I actually found an easier method.

Comment: Prolog isn't like other languages in how it handles variables. In Prolog, within a clause, you can't modify a variable again once it's instantiated. `append(X, B, X)` says, *List `X` is the the list `X` with `B` appended to it*. The only list that satisfies this rule is `B = []`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several misunderstandings. First, lists and their elements are confused which leads to the "dotted pair" that is `|a]`. Then, it seems that the role of variables is not clear to you.

In the goal `append([1,2,3],A,X)` both `A` and `X` are supposed to be lists. However, you set `A` to `a` which is not a list. The problem behind is that `append/3` accepts any term for the second argument. To see this, just look at its answers:

```
?- append([1,2,3],A,X).
X = [1,2,3|A].
```

So the `A` can be anything, but it should be rather only a list.

```
?- A = a, append([1,2,3],A,X).
   A = a, X = [1,2,3|a].
```

Note that `append/3` insists that the first argument is a list (or a partial list). Then once you have a bad list, you can no longer append it further. That is:

```
?- A = a, append([1,2,3],A,X), append(X, _, _).
   false.
```

Note that I did not use your definition literally. Instead, I replaced certain arguments by `_` since they cannot help.

The second problem stems from the goal `append(X, B, X)`.  This goal, can **only** be true if `B = []`. Let's try this out:

```
?- append(X, B, X).
   X = [], B = []
;  X = [_A], B = []
;  X = [_A,_B], B = []
;  X = [_A,_B,_C], B = []
;  ... .
```

And:

```
?- B = [_|_], append(X, B, X).
   loops.
```

While there are many answers for `X`, `B` is always `[]`.

Comment: I misunderstood how `append` works. I thought `append(X, B, X)` would overwrite list X rather than making a new list out of the two X and B.

Comment: @user3546630: Try to enter queries for append - as many different goals you can! This helps you to learn much faster than by defining predicates. Think of `Ls = [a,b,c,d], append(Xs,Xs,Ls)` and the like.

Answer (score 0):

`append` appends lists. So you want to make a list with a single element to append it to another list:

```
makelist(A, B, C, X) :- append([1, 2, 3], [A], X). % What's the purpose of B and C, btw?
```

Also you can add items to the beginning of a list more effectively:

```
makelist(A, B, C, [A | [1, 2, 3]]).
```